# While Opening Android Studio I am getting Error Link in the body?

Tags: android, android-studio

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4seao.png)

Please Help me to solve this error in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates an issue in `IDE` plugins.

Remove the Android Studio folder in this path `~/.local/share/Google/`.
This should fix your issue.

If your issue is not resolved by doing this you must read this article
[NoSuchMethodError](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/11876922)

Answer (score 0):

Some plugin is IDE causing this error. You can delete all and redownload them again.

`For Ubuntu`,

Delete the folder .local/share/google and Open android studio.

`For Windows`,

Delete the folder C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Google or C:\Users{USER}.AndroidStudio4.1\config\plugins

`For Mac`,

Delete the marketplace folder ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio/marketplace